Centering a div inside a container vertically and horizontally
So basically I am working on a layout where I need to center a div inside a container both vertically and horizontally. I want to use Flexbox, but I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong.
Here's my code:
  <style>
    .container {
      display: flex;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: lightgray;
    }
    
    .centered {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: coral;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  </style>

The div isn’t centering properly. Can someone help me figure out what’s wrong ?
